# Will IE9 now be supporting WebSocket?

Tags: websocket, internet-explorer-9

The question's pretty straightforward and the old topic is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377096/will-ie9-support-webgl-and-or-websockets). I'm hoping to get up-to-date answers since IE9's gonna be released this March 14, 2011.

In addition, I would also like to ask when will Firefox and Opera be supporting WebSockets?

Comment: Did you miss the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377096/will-ie9-support-webgl-and-or-websockets/4678412#4678412) to the question you linked?

Comment: He said it's in RC, though. I still don't know about the _final_ release.

Answer (score 7):

I've been following both the development of IE9 and I also participate in the HyBi WG (WebSockets protocol). Microsoft has been keeping the demo implementation of WebSockets up to date with the latest revisions of the protocol, however, I suspect that the initial release of IE9 will not have built-in WebSockets support. It will probably not be until IE10 unless they start to see it as a big competitive disadvantage in which case we will likely see it added in a IE9 update before IE10.

Firefox will likely support WebSockets in an update to FF4 or with FF5 (but the plan is that 5 will come out this year). Also, you can turn on the current implementation in FF4 using a about:config option.

I have no idea about Opera. They are interesting in the protocol but they've been pretty silent on the HyBi list.

Also, if you need WebSockets right now you can always use the Flash shim/fallback [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js).

**Update**:

I forgot, Opera 11.00 does have WebSockets support built-in but disabled. Go to *opera:config* and search for *WebSocket*.

So in summary, just about every modern browser has WebSockets support in some way either built-in and enabled (Chrome, Safari, iOS), built-in but disabled (FF4 and Opera), as a downloadable add-on (IE9), or using the web-socket-js Flash emulator (everything except iOS).

Comment: I had installation issues in NodeJS so I'm currently using Jetty -- too bad it's only supported by Chrome and Safari though, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, The RTW version of IE9 does NOT support a websocket type... :(

UPDATE: The IE team is developing websockets for their browser, but it's not included in the initial release because the standard is in a fluid state. Although the implementation is stable, the standard isn't. If you want to test it out in IE9, you can by downloading it here:
http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/

You can hear more about it by listening to this DotNetRocks podcast:
http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=648

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

IE9 does support WebSockets but not as a "built-in" functionality. You have to download it as a plugin from http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com

The reason given by microsoft for not including in default setup is - the standard is unstable and keeps changing and in default setup only stable HTML5 standards shall be included.

So in a way IE10 as of now will also not include.

The HTML5Labs site will provide "experimental" support to unstable standards.

Comment: Could you update the download link? By following the current link I can't seem to find the plugin for IE9. Thanks :)

Comment: please update the download link, i'm need it for knowledges and support ie9